# Couchbase query error 5000 (open C:\Couchbase\Server\var\lib\couchbase\tmp\scan-results5960831968761: The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: go, couchbase, sql++

We have a 3 node Couchbase server 6.0.2 EE cluster on Windows 2016. We fire n1ql queries against a bucket using golang SDK. Every third query execution generates this error:

```
[5000] open D:\\Couchbase\\Server\\var\\lib\\couchbase\\tmp\\scan-results5960831968761: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

We tried to restart/kill the query job on all three nodes, that didn't solve the issue! Couchbase was still insisting to find the scan-results[\d]+

We didn't find anything in couchbase public forums

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

we solved the problem by creating an empty tmp folder in var\lib\couchbase on all nodes. after that the query error above didn't occur.

Comment: Installation must have created it. Check this out https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/backfill.html